# Generate Random string is not recognised as keyword in robot framework

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I tried

random stuff

```
${commentText} = Generate Random String  100  [LETTERS]
```

The user enters text to a text field `id=textId  ${commentText}`
I have placed Library String at the suite level too but when ran the test, it says `no keyword with name ${commentText} = Generate Random String 100 [LETTERS] found`

Comment: please fix the formatting. It's hard to see what part of that last paragraph is part of the test, and none of the test (or keyword?) has proper markup.

Answer (score 4):

> it says no keyword with name ${commentText} = Generate Random String 100 [LETTERS] found

Take a close look at the error message. I'll add emphasis to make it more clear:

no keyword with name **${commentText} = Generate Random String 100 [LETTERS]** found

In other words, it's not complaining about a keyword named `Generate Random String`, it's complaining about a keyword named `${commentText} = Generate Random String 100 [LETTERS]`

This happens when you don't separate the individual parts of the statement with two or more spaces, causing robot to think the entire line is the name of the keyword.

The correct syntax is this:

```
${commentText}=  Generate Random String  100  [LETTERS]
```

Notice that there are two spaces between `${commentText}`, `Generate Random String`, `100`, and `[LETTERS]`

Answer (score 1):

Could you place exactly the same code that you use? I would say that you are not using proper delimiter, like 4 spaces:

```
${commentText} =    Generate Random String    100    [LETTERS]
```